# How to trigger conditional if every date attribute is nil for current month of this year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to trigger conditional with `@future_challenges` if `deadline` is not equal to `Date.current.year.month`?

**controller**

```
@future_challenges = current_user.challenges.unaccomplished.order("deadline ASC").select{ |challenge| challenge.deadline > Date.current if challenge.deadline.present? }
```

**view**

```
<% if @future_challenges != Date.current.year.month %> # Is giving true even if there are challenges with deadline in current month of this year
  <div style="margin-top: -4px;"></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `@future_challenges` is an array. You need to loop through `@future_challenges` for check in the view.

Comment: Isn't that a lot of looping @Emu for such a small purpose? Maybe I should create a new controller method like `future_challenges_current_month`?

Comment: I don't know what is your actual purpose. But the query you've done in controller returns an array. And in the view to check if current month is in the array you can use `include?`

Comment: My actual purpose is to reduce the top margin by `-4` if there are no challenges with a deadline in the current month @Emu. How would I use `include?` I tried, `@future_challenges[Date.current.year.month].include?`. I got `nil` error even tho it's a conditional and shouldn't be `nil` since I have a challenge in the current month set.

Comment: you could use `@future_challenges.include? (Date.current.year.month)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I have misunderstood then in the controller all you would need to do is something like:

```
@future_challenges = current_user.challenges.where("deadline >= ?", Date.current.at_beginning_of_month)
```

and then in the view just check the number of entries:

```
<% if @future_challenges.empty?  %>
  <div style="margin-top: -4px;"></div>
<% end %>
```